# Google Admin Directory API "JsonSerializationException"

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

Starting yesterday our user provisioning process that utilizes the Admin Directory API for creating Google accounts started encountering a JsonSerializationException when pulling a list of users. We are using the .NET API and have not made any recent changes to the code. I know there was a recent scheduled planned downtime in relation to the discontinuation of JSON-RPC support but that window was only for a few hours and we have been experiencing this error now for almost 24 hours. We run a provisioning process for 6 different client domains in G-Suite for Education and 5 are failing even though the are all using the same process and code. The error that is occurring below is from the ListRequest Execute() method:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path 'users[0].customSchemas', line 42, position 24.

We are specifying a value in the ListRequest CustomFieldMask property. If I comment that out the process runs error free. I have also tried updating the API to the most recent version 1.46.

Thanks for any help you can provide,
Ron

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

Approximately 30 hours after the errors began they stopped with no changes on my end so I am assuming there was something going on on the Google server that our process was connecting to.